# How do I parse "but that shall be accounted the promised share of this traitor"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

This comes from Tolkien's "The Hobbit", towards the end, where Thorin talks about giving part of the treasure hoard to the elves and to the people of Lake-town, in order to redeem the Arkenstone, which Bilbo had secretly given to Bard.

Here's a more complete passage:

> It was rightly guessed that I could not forbear to redeem the Arkenstone, the treasure of my house. For it I will give one fourteenth share of the hoard in silver and gold, setting aside the gems; **but that shall be accounted the promised share of this traitor**, and with that reward he shall depart, and you can divide it as you will.

(emphasis mine)

I can understand the meaning of the passage. I just can't figure out how to parse the bold part, **in terms of grammar**:

- "shall be accounted" is in the passive voice, to "the promised share" can't be a direct object;
- Is "the promised share" the subject? But then what's the "that" doing before the "shall be accounted"?

I'm starting to suspect that this is a case of mandative subjunctive, where the "that" is the opening conjunction and the subject ("the promised share") is put after the verb ("shall be accounted").

Can somebody confirm or correct me?

Comment: "That" is the subject, "shall be accounted" is the verb phrase, "the promised share" is the direct object.

Comment: In the active the verb is "to account X Y" meaning to value X as equal to Y, where Y is an object complement; c.f. "to account him a lucky man". This precise usage doesn't seem to be in any dictionary I've consulted, but it's common with verbs like "judge".

Comment: I don't think it's a mandative subjunctive - that would be *Thorin ordered that that [the one fourteenth] be accounted the promised share of the traitor*. I would just call it a complement. I don't think the clause is any different from *but that shall be counted as the share promised to Bilbo*.

Comment: I agree with rchivers. "that" (part of the hoard) is the object of the verb "accounted." And "the promised share of this traitor" is the complement.

Comment: The patient is not a subject in the passive voice, @OldBrixtonian.  In the active voice, yes:  "We shall account that [as] his share."  In the original model, "that" is the subject and "the promised share of this traitor" is a predicate nominative *subject* complement.  The predicating phrase "shall be accounted" is copular.

Comment: @Gary Botnovcan: So is it not the same structure as "the event was deemed a great success"? It seems not.

Comment: Why not?  That, too, is copular when passive, complexly transitive when active.  In the active, it's "someone [ deems / has deemed / &c. ] the event a great success" -- subject as agent, object as patient, and an object complement.  In the passive, the agent is an optional adjunct (typically using the preposition "by") the patient is the subject and the complement shares its referent with that.  My point was simply that it's a mistake to point at a subject and call it an object.  That that "that" is the patient of "accounted" is where we agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| **that** | **subject** |
| **shall be accounted** | **verb (future passive)** |
| **the promised share of this traitor** | **direct object** |

***To account*** is a transitive verb used in the passive voice here. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/account) defines it giving a similar example:

> ***account*** *verb [T + obj + noun/adj]* (JUDGE)
> to think of someone or something in the stated way:
>
> - She ***was accounted** a genius* by all who knew her work.

Comment: Yes, after looking at the definition of Merriam-Webster, and comparing with the French translation of the passage, I believe that this is the correct interpretation. I simply never knew that "to account" can be transitive. I've never seen this usage before.

Answer (score 0):

In the early chapters, Bilbo was promised a payment of one fourteenth of the treasure in return for his assistance on the quest.

Thorin is saying that he will pay Bilbo's promised share to get the Arkenstone back, and Bilbo can go home with nothing.

The meaning of the individual words, as follows:

"**this traitor**" - Bilbo
"**that**" - the money offered to the town
"**promised share**" - the money promised to Bilbo
"**shall be accounted**" - we will regard them as being the same thing

Comment: OP is asking about the grammar, not semantics, involved.